# How can I execute php code in mediawiki?

Tags: php, mediawiki

I would like put code php in mediawiki but, when I put the code of php, I see the same. If I write:

```
<?php
echo "hello"
?>
```

I should see:
hello
But I see the same:

```
<?php
echo "hello"
?>
```

I have tried to use this extension: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:RawCodeFile

But I don't understand/know this part:
Go to your extension subdir and:

```
 git clone //github com/GeSHi/geshi-1.0.git
```

It should create a "geshi-1.0-master" dir, after renaming as geshi-1.0, RawCodeFile will find it.

```
 git clone //github com/GeSHi/geshi-1.0.git
```

And I can't fix, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: So your intention is to run PHP code in an Wiki article?

Comment: I don't think the extension you link to does what you think it does. Geshi is a syntax highlighter. The extension is for displaying and sharing code snippets, not for making backend code somehow magically execute when a page is rendered. If you _do_ want some PHP code to run each time an article is rendered, you should find an appropriate [hook](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks#Hooks_grouped_by_function), and write an extension to do that for you.

Comment: Yes, I want to see in a wiki article, a web of mediawiki. After time, I see that with this extension: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Include

I can do it. Thanks for all.

Comment: You're maybe searching for the [Include extension](https://mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Include) for MediaWiki wikis.

Comment: Thanks for the replys. I used this extension: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Include This is not perfect, but it look like to work.